# oAuth: request token invalidates current access token

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Our app already implements oAuth to obtain the access token and secret from Intuit, and all works well.

The app takes into account that users may have multiple QBO companies. Consequently, when a user tries to authorize access to one company, our app checks whether this company has been already authorized, and if it has, the app lets the user know so and does not try to re-authorize the company.

The way we implemented this is as follows. When the authorization process starts, we send or app the list of companies (realm ID) which have been authorized. The user clicks the "Connect to QuickBooks" button and follows the wizard. Internally the app gets the request token and it is ready to make the access token request. The request token request gets us the realm ID so we can compare it with the list of already authorized companies. If the company has been authorized we do not request the access token and let the user know that the company has already been authorized.

Up until a week ago this used to work -i.e. in this case, because the app does not make a request for the access token, the access token the app has is still valid. However, now something seems to have changed so that when the app makes gets the request token, even though it does not ask for the access token, the existing access token is not valid anymore and the user need to re-authorize the company again.

Has something changed in the oAuth flow implementation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OAuth tokens are valid for 180 days (by default). So, please check if existing tokens are getting more than 180 days old. If so, please use 'reconnect api'.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/v2/docs/0050_quickbooks_api/0020_authentication_and_authorization/oauth_management_api#Reconnect

One suggestion:

You can implement SSO (using 'sign in with intuit' wizard) in you app. That way you can relate end-user's SSO URL with OAuth tokens of their company while persisting those in your app's db. For the very first time, end user will generate tokens through C2QB flow. Next time onwards whenever the end user will sign in, your app should retrieve their oauth tokens using his SSO identifier(your app should show 'Disconnect' option instead of C2QB if he already has an established connection).